# Associating aiohttp requests with the responses

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

I would simply like to associate responses from aiohttp asynchronous HTTP requests with an identifier. I am using the following code to hit the API and extract contactproperty object which requires an external field (contacid) in order to call its API:

```
def get_contact_properties(self, office_name, api_key, ids, chunk_size=100, **params):
    properties_pages = []
    batch = 0
    while True:

        chunk_ids = [ids[i] for i in range(batch * chunk_size + 1, chunk_size * (1 + batch) + 1)]
        urls = ["{}/{}".format(self.__get_base_url(), "contacts/{}/properties?api_key={}".format(contactid, api_key))
                for contactid in chunk_ids]

        responses_raw = self.get_responses(urls, self.get_office_token(office_name), chunk_size)
        try:
            responses_json = [json.loads(response_raw) for response_raw in responses_raw]
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        valid_responses = self.__get_valid_contact_properties_responses(responses_json)
        properties_pages.append(valid_responses)


        if len(valid_responses) < chunk_size:  # this is how we know there are no more pages with data
            break
        else:
            batch = batch + 1
```

ids is a `list` of ids. The problem is that I do not know which response corresponds to which id so that later  I can link it to contact entity using contacid. This is my fetch() function so I was wondering how to edit this function to return the contactid along with output.

```
async def __fetch(self, url, params, session):
    async with session.get(url, params=params) as response:
        output = await response.read()
        return (output)

async def __bound_fetch(self, sem, url, params, session):
    # Getter function with semaphore.
    async with sem:
        output = await self.__fetch(url, params, session)
        return output
```

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the **url** (or whatever key identifies your request) together with the **output**.

Regarding using the data, I think you should read the response directly as JSON, especially since aiohttp can do this for you automatically.

```py
async def __fetch(self, url, params, session):
    async with session.get(url, params=params) as response:
        try:
            data = await response.json()
        except ValueError as exc:
            print(exc)
            return None
        return data

async def __bound_fetch(self, sem, url, params, session):
    # Getter function with semaphore.
    async with sem:
        output = await self.__fetch(url, params, session)
        return {"url": url, "data": data}
```

You did not post the `get_responses` function but I'm guessing something like this should work:

```py
responses = self.get_responses(urls, self.get_office_token(office_name), chunk_size)
```

Responses will be a list of `{"url": url, data: "data"}` (data can be None for invalid responses); however with the code above one invalid request will not affect the others.

Comment: Do you mean url instead of params? because params is empty but url has the contact id. Can you please complete your answer? because __bound_fetch returns  a dict so how can I pass it to json.loads??? 
responses_json = [json.loads(response_raw) for response_raw in responses_raw]